# ¿Cómo Crear una carpeta con todos los permisos y copiar un archivo usando C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, imagen

Lo que quisiera conseguir es que la imagen que seleccione pueda copiarla en un folder de destino para que desde ahi pueda tomar siempra la ruta que yo le ordene a mi sistema.

Código para copiar el archivo:

```
if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // display image in picture box
    picFebChange.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
    // image file path
    lblRuta.Text = open.FileName;
    
    if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images")==true)
    {
        File.Copy( @"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images",lblRuta.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images");
        File.Copy( @"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images",lblRuta.Text);
    }
}
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer la carpeta en donde quiero guardar mi imagen no tiene los permisos, necesarios, ¿cómo modificar ese aspecto al momento de crearla?

## Actualización

Ya mejoré mi código, para darle los permisos a mi carpeta, pero aun asi me sigue saliendo el mismo error:

Código Nuevo:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images");
DirectorySecurity sec = Directory.GetAccessControl(@"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images");

SecurityIdentifier everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
sec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.Modify | FileSystemRights.Synchronize, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
Directory.SetAccessControl(@"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images", sec);

File.Copy(@"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images", lblRuta.Text,true);
```

Comment: El problema no es de programación, el mensaje dice bien claro que el usuario que ejecuta el programa no tiene permisos para acceder a esa ruta. Si no hay permisos, da igual el programa que hagas o en qué lenguaje, el sistema operativo denegará el acceso.

Comment: Hola David :) revisa la respuesta que puse, me parece que el problema pincipal es este `@"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images"` estás indicando el nombre de una carpeta y no el nombre de un archivo

Comment: @Flxtr, ya modifique mi codigo de acuerdo a lo que me recomendaste, pero me salio el siguiente error:  El archivo de destino "C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images" es un directorio, no un archivo.

Comment: Sí claro, ese error es muy descriptivo, para solucionarlo, en lugar de `@"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images"` complementa con el archivo que deseas copiar `@"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images\NombreArchivo.txt"` eso es debido a que estás utilizando el nombre de un directorio donde deberías usar el nombre de un archivo :)

Comment: Ya lo modifique con el archivo y la carpeta en su lugar y el valor boolean, pero regreso al problema de la pregunta, acceso no autorizado :)

Comment: Ok David, intentemos algo, así como tienes el código agrega la línea que puse en mi respuesta `File.Attribute(....`, también puede ser un problema de atributos, me avisas qué gestos hace tu aplicación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un detalle que veo es que no indicas realmente el nombre del archivo que deseas copiar `@"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images"`, con esto indicas el nombre de una carpeta. El método `File.Copy()` acepta 2 y 3 parámetros según la sobrecarga, para esto te recomiendo usar `("Archivo", "Carpeta de destino", BoolParasobreEscribirElArchivo):`

También el problema se puede deber a que el archivo ya existe, intenta sobreescribiendo el archivo con el tercer parámetro en el método `File.Copy(archivo, destino, sobreescritura);`:

```
File.Copy(@"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images\NombreArchivo.txt", lblRuta.Text, true);
```

Documentación oficial en **[este link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx)**.

## Actualización

Después de haber copiado el archivo, se deben asignar atributos normales, ya que si contiene otros como *solo lectura* u *oculto* también puede causar conflicto:

```
File.Copy(@"C:\Users\NQ054\Pictures\Images\NombreArchivo.txt", lblRuta.Text, true);
File.SetAttributes(lblRuta.Text, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas intentando crear archivos en la carpeta especial de UserProfile(`System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile`) que según la documentación del mismo en este [enlace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) y cito textualmente

> Las aplicaciones no deben crear archivos ni carpetas en este nivel;
>   deben poner sus datos bajo las ubicaciones a las que hace referencia
>   ApplicationData